# Given $(m-2)x^2-4x+3=3-x^2+2nx$, compute the value of $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $$(m-2)x^2-4x+3=3-x^2+2nx$$ Compute the value of $m$.

$$(m-2)x^2-4x+3=3-x^2+2nx
\\mx^2+(-4m-4)x+7=-x^2+2nx+3
\\m=-1, n=0$$

The answer is $m=1,n=-2$, please tell me where did I go wrong

Comment: There is no linear term in $(m-2)x^2$, it's purely quadratic in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The coefficient of $x^2$ on the left of the equal sign is $(m-2)$ and on the right it is $-1$